# Android: Can we read file from /data/data/ folder using su command in non rooted device

Tags: android

Hi everyone i m get confused about "su" command is it working in non rooted device. As i want to read a file from /data/data folder. On stackover I can different solution to read file from this folder using "su" but its not working for me on my non rooted device.

Please some body suggest me.

As i try to copy file from /data/data to /sdcard but it didn't work for me

```
String comando = "cp -r /data/data/local/data.txt /sdcard/123/";
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n)";
        os.flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

su binaries are only available in rooted phones.

**What happens when rooting phones?**
/system is mounted with read-write permissions.
su binaries are copied to /system/bin or /system/xbin folder.
A root manager app is installed.[Like SuperSu or SuperUser].This is so that apps don't misuse the root permissions and prevents malicious files from ruining your android mobile.

**What can you do now?**
I don't think there's any way of copying or reading files from /data folder without root permissions.